# How to clamp the output of CIPerspectiveTransformWithExtent filter?

Tags: graphics, core-image, homography

I'm using a `CIPerspectiveTransformWithExtent` filter to apply homographies (perspective warp) to images on OS X. So far, so good, and I can get the desired warping applied to my images.

I'm still struggling however with the border behavior. I would like the output of the filter to be clipped outside the original image domain:

- I managed to do it for the lower and left borders by shifting the origin of the `inputExtent` rectangle of the correct amount. For example, if the lower left corner is projected to `x = -10` then using `extent.origin.x = 10` will correctly clip the left border;
- on the other hand, the upper and right borders are always shown in the output image. For example, if the rightmost corner is projected to `x = width + 10`, setting the extent via `extent.origin.x = 0, extent.size.width = width;` does not work an the rightmost corner remains visible.

Am I doing anything wrong here? or maybe I'm not trying the right way to achieve my goal?